# Submit timestamp to mysql database with php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli, timestamp

I have this database (mysql):

[image]

And I have code:

```
$day = $app->request->post('day');
            $startLocation = $app->request->post('startLocation');
            $datum = new DateTime();
            $startTime = $datum->getTimestamp(); //this line is IMPORTANT
            global $user_id;
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // creating new task
            $day_id = $db->createDay($user_id, $day, $startLocation, $startTime); ETC...
```

but I cant submit that `timestamp` data into database in `startTime` witch have `type timestamp`

Why? How to do that?

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes, can you please provide the error text?

Comment: no,becouse backend is REST api service on which I try to add data ... I send this to database: startTime: 1417878370, but that data not been sbmited on database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your column data type is `TIMESTAMP`, then it should be:

```
$datum = new DateTime();
$startTime = $datum->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note: `->getTimestamp()` returns **unix timestamp**

And modify your wrapper function:

```
public function createDay($user_id, $day, $startLocation, $startTime) { 
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,startLocation,startTime) VALUES(?,?,?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $day, $startLocation, $startTime); // change the d into s in your types
    $result = $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: hm, again dont work, I send this data: startTime: "2014-12-06 16:10:05" , but that data is not in database

Comment: @LaraBeginer make sure that all fields are provided, you have 8 fields in total

Comment: maybe is my function problem:  public function createDay($user_id, $day, $startLocation, $startTime) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO days(day,startLocation,startTime) VALUES(?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssd", $day, $startLocation, $startTime);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

Comment: thanks, that right but with bind_param "sss" works fine ... thans again

Comment: @LaraBeginer yes, that was i was going to point out, you're inputting a string now, not a digit. im glad this helped